# Why are my required inputs being highlighted before the user enters text?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, input

I am building a React component that contains a login/registration form. Which form displays is determined by the user by clicking on the relevant tab, which updates the values of `reg` and `log` in state. However, my issue is that if the user enters text into the first two inputs of either form, if they toggle to the other form, the first two inputs of that form will be highlighted red, even though the user hasn't entered anything into those inputs. I have taken some screenshots to demonstrate what I mean:

[image]
[image]

Is anybody able to explain why this is happening? It's only a small issue, but I'd like to at least understand why it's happening :)

Here is the form inside the `render()` method of the component:

```
<aside className="logReg">
    <ul className="tabGroup">
        <li className={`tab${this.state.reg ? " active" : ""}`} onClick={this.handleClick}>Register</li>
        <li className={`tab${this.state.log ? " active" : ""}`} onClick={this.handleClick}>Login</li>
    </ul>
    {this.state.reg ?
        <form className="form" id="register" />
            <label className="label">Full Name</label>
            <input className="input" type="text" onChange={ this.handleRegName } value={ this.state.register.name } required/>

            <label className="label">Email</label>
            <input className="input" type="email" onChange={ this.handleRegEmail } value={ this.state.register.email } required/>

            <label className="label">Password</label>
            <input className="input" type="password" onChange={ this.handleRegPass } value={ this.state.register.pass } required/>

            <label className="label">Password Confirmation</label>
            <input className="input" type="password" onChange={ this.handleRegConf } value={ this.state.register.conf } required/>

            <button className="formButton" type="submit">Register</button>
        </form>
    :
        <form className="form" id="login" >
            <label className="label">Email</label>
            <input className="input" type="email" onChange={ this.handleLogEmail } value={ this.state.login.email } required/>

            <label className="label">Password</label>
            <input className="input" type="password" onChange={ this.handleLogPass } value={ this.state.login.pass } required/>

            <button className="formButton" type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
    }
</aside>
```

This is the structure of my state:

```
        this.state = {
            reg: true,
            register: {
                name: "",
                email: "",
                pass: "",
                conf: ""
            },
            log: false,
            login: {
                email: "",
                pass: ""
            }
        }
```

Here are a couple of my methods (all of the `handleRegEmail`/`handleLogName` etc. follow the same structure as `handleRegName(e)` below):

```
    handleClick(){
        let currentReg = this.state.reg;
        let currentLog = this.state.log;
        this.setState({
            reg: !currentReg,
            log: !currentLog
        })
    }

    handleRegName(e){
        let registerCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.register));
        registerCopy.name = e.currentTarget.value;
        this.setState({ 
            register: registerCopy
        });
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you should probably include the logic of the component too. Also wow, still using class components? Also I don't think the way you are commenting the action and method works on jsx, try removing it

Comment: @JenaroCalviño, I have updated my original post with some of the logic. And yes, I've used class components for now as this app was initially quite small/simple, however now it's growing I'm planning on converting most of my components to functional components a little bit further down the line!

Answer (score 0):

Check where you implement the logic used to validate your forms, the cause of your issue might be there.

Also try adding `name` attribute to your input elements and use that for validation?

Maybe you use `type['...']` for your validation?

Hope any of these help

Comment: I haven't added any of my own validation to this form yet, I believe the only client-side validation currently is the `required` attribute on each input.